# Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error. How to fix it

Tags: php, wordpress

This plugin work fine on my localhost but when i want active this plugin on client site i see this error Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home2/alchimi1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-fieldmanager-master/fieldmanager.php on line 120
```

you can check this code here https://github.com/alleyinteractive/wordpress-fieldmanager/blob/master/fieldmanager.php

What i should to do ?

---

Comment: check the version of php on your server.

Comment: Sometimes a plugin gets corrupted when uploading. Either delete the plugin from your wp-admin plugin manager, or if you can;t get into wp-admin, Log into your cpanel, navigate to the plugin folder and delete the plugin. Then reinstall and see if it works.

Comment: i have re-install but same thing. I think i happened due to php version....

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with PHP version, check your version.

In version 5.3.0 anonymous functions become available.

Source:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

### Checking version:

Create an blank file in your server and append:

`<?php phpinfo() ?>`

Or use command line: `php -i` or `php -v`